# Sorting a multi-array by the inner value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

i have this array

```
[Computers] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 78
            [category_name] => Computers
            [sort_order] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 70
            [category_name] => Computers
            [sort_order] => 1
        )

)


[Scanners] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 65
            [category_name] => Scanners
            [sort_order] => 6
        )

)

[Printers] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 58
            [category_name] => Printers
            [sort_order] => 3
        )

)
[Screens] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 62
            [category_name] => Screens
            [sort_order] => 2
        )

)
```

I cant seem to find a way to sort the array based on the key `sort_order`. I tried all the examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value) but no luck. I need the arrays in this order

```
Computers
Screens
Printers
Scanners
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP sort multidimensional array by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: If you look at my question I clearly state that I have tried all these solutions with no luck because there are internal arrays in my question

Comment: So your actual problem is how to adopt the answers from the other question for your data?

Comment: Can you show what the finally array should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);

    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
            foreach ($array[$ii] as $i => $val) {
                $sorter[$ii]=$val[$key];
            }
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $element => $value) {
        $ret[$element]=$array[$element];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}

 aasort($array,"sort_order");
```

Comment: @Tamer What sorting algorithm is that?

Comment: It is at least not nearly as efficient as using a correct data structure and a built in function like usort :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value/2699110#2699110

Comment: "Attribution" means that if you copy a solution from another answer, please point out where you copied it from.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have the sort parameter at the wrong level. You want to sort the highest level right? So put the sorting parameter there as well. The following data structure would make much more sense:

```
[Computers] => Array
(
    [sort_order] => 1,
    [data] => array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 78,
                [category_name] => Computers,
                [sort_order] => 1,
            )
    )
)
```

If you nest the sort order as deep in the data structure as you have it will make for horrible sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient:

```
uasort($yourArray,
       create_function('$a,$b','return $a[0]["sort_order"] > $b[0]["sort_order"];'));
```